Maclaurin series of logarithmic expression
I have been considering the Maclaurin series of $x/ln(1+x+\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^3}{3!}+...\frac{x^n}{n!})$ about x=0.In the case n=1 I found the first few terms by direct calculation. For n>1 I have seen the following result:$$x/ln(1+x+\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^3}{3!}+....\frac{x^n}{n!})=1+\frac{x^n}{(n+1)!}-\frac{x^{n+1}}{(n+2)n!}+....$$.
The above result seems plausible, for as n tends to $\infty$, both sides tend to 1.However I have found proving this result difficult,having tried for example l'Hopital's rule, and any assistance would be appreciated.

Define the function to equal 1 at x=0. By l'hopital's rule it will be smooth.

Here's at least a starting point.
First, we use the fact that the Maclaurin series for $\frac{x}{\ln(1 + x)}$ is defined by the Gregory coefficients $G_n$ such that
$$\frac{x}{\ln(1 + x)} = 1 + \sum_{n = 1}^\infty G_n x^n$$
As a result, the Laurent expansion for $\frac{1}{\ln(1 + x)}$ about $x = 0$ is just
$$\frac{1}{\ln(1 + x)} = \frac{1}{x} + \sum_{k = 0}^\infty G_{k + 1} x^k$$
and so if we substitute our polynomial $P_n(x) = x + \frac{x^2}{2} + \ldots + \frac{x^n}{n!}$ instead, we get
$$\frac{1}{\ln(1 + P_n(x))} = \frac{1}{P_n(x)} + \sum_{k = 1}^\infty G_{k + 1} (P_n(x))^k$$
Multiply the whole thing by $x$ again, we have
$$\frac{x}{\ln(1 + P_n(x))} = \frac{x}{P_n(x)} + \sum_{k = 0}^\infty G_{k + 1} x (P_n(x))^k$$
The first term becomes
$$\begin{eqnarray} \frac{x}{P_n(x)} & = & \frac{x}{x + \frac{x^2}{x} + \ldots + \frac{x^n}{n!}} \\
& = & \frac{1}{1 + x + \frac{x^2}{6} + \ldots + \frac{x^{n - 1}}{n!}} \\
& = & 1 + \sum_{k = 1}^\infty (-1)^k \left( \frac{x}{2} + \frac{x^2}{6} + \ldots + \frac{x^{n - 1}}{n!} \right)^k \\
& = & 1 + \sum_{k = 1}^\infty (-1)^k x^k \left( \frac{1}{2} + \frac{x}{6} + \ldots + \frac{x^{n - 2}}{n!} \right)^k \end{eqnarray}$$
using a geometric series expansion.
If we bring that back in to the previous expression and do a bit of rearrangement, we get
$$\begin{eqnarray} \frac{x}{\ln\left(1 + x + \ldots + \frac{x^n}{n!}\right)} & = & 1 + \sum_{k = 1}^\infty (-1)^k x^k \left( \frac{1}{2} + \frac{x}{6} + \ldots + \frac{x^{n - 2}}{n!} \right)^k \\
&& + \sum_{k = 1}^\infty G_k \left(x + \frac{x^2}{2} + \ldots + \frac{x^n}{n!} \right)^k \\
& = & 1 + \sum_{k = 1}^\infty (-1)^k x^k \left( \frac{1}{2} + \frac{x}{6} + \ldots + \frac{x^{n - 2}}{n!} \right)^k \\
&& + \sum_{k = 1}^\infty G_k x^k \left(1 + \frac{x}{2} + \ldots + \frac{x^{n - 1}}{n!} \right)^k \end{eqnarray}$$
From here, you can in theory expand out both terms and collect all of the powers of $x^k$ together, and then potentially apply some identities relating to the Gregory coefficients to find the expansion you're looking for or at least demonstrate the behaviours you've already observed hold.
Alternatively, to prove only that the Maclaurin coefficients for $x, x^2, \ldots, x^{n - 1}$ vanish, you can do the following (subject to proving that everything converges appropriately):
$$\begin{eqnarray} \ln\left(1 + x + \frac{x^2}{2} + \ldots + \frac{x^n}{n!} \right)  & = & \ln\left(e^x - \frac{x^{n + 1}}{(n + 1)!} - \frac{x^{n + 2}}{(n + 2)!} - \ldots \right) \\
& = & \ln\left(e^x - x^{n + 1} Q(x) \right) \mbox{ where } Q(x) = \frac{1}{(n + 1)!} + \frac{x}{(n + 2)!} + \ldots \\
& = & x + \ln\left(1 - e^{-x} x^{n + 1} Q(x) \right) \\
\frac{x}{\ln\left(1 + x + \frac{x^2}{2} + \ldots + \frac{x^n}{n!} \right)} & = & \frac{x}{x + \ln\left(1 - e^{-x} x^{n + 1} Q(x) \right)} \\
& = & \frac{1}{1 + \frac{1}{x} \ln\left(1 - e^{-x} x^{n + 1} Q(x) \right)} \\
& = & 1 - \frac{1}{x} \ln\left(1 - e^{-x} x^{n + 1} Q(x)\right) + \left(\frac{1}{x} \ln\left(1 - e^{-x} x^{n + 1} Q(x)\right) \right)^2 - \ldots
\end{eqnarray}$$
then you just show that the first $n - 1$ coefficients of the Maclaurin series for $\ln\left(1 - e^{-x} x^{n + 1} Q(x)\right)$ are all zero because you can expand out $\ln(1 - x) = -x - 2x^2 - 3x^3 - \ldots$. This method is almost certainly much worse than the first approach for all of the non-zero coefficients though.

Thank you for your answer. I was unaware of the Gregory coefficients so found this information very useful.
